# UWP app background task stopps when mouse/keyboard is disconnected

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I have an UWP app that should act as an information display that should run 24/7 in full-screen mode. I has an background task that dose some rest requests and parses the result and passes it back to the UI. It works as intended.

BUT!

I want to start this on my system that should be used and then disconnect the keyboard and mouse and walk away. The problem is that when I do this the background task wont run.

It can run for days as long as the mouse/keyboard is plugged in but the very second I disconnect them the background task is not executed.

Does Windows handle mouse/keyboard disconnect as if the app looses focus and subsequently suspends all background work?

EDIT:

This is how I create my background task:

```
    private async void MainPage_OnLoaded(object _sender, RoutedEventArgs _e)
    {
        var registration = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.SingleOrDefault(_t => _t.Value.Name == BACKGROUND_TASK_NAME).Value;

        if (registration != null)
        {
            backgroundTask = (BackgroundTaskRegistration)registration;
            Logger.Information("Found background task with {ID} in application settings and found it registered, reusing it", backgroundTask.TaskId);
        }
        else
        {
            var backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

            Logger.Information("backGroundAccessStatus is {Status}", backgroundAccessStatus);

            if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedBySystemPolicy ||
                backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
            {
                Logger.Error("Cannot create background task");
                return;
            }

            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
            {
                Name = BACKGROUND_TASK_NAME,
                TaskEntryPoint = TASK_ENTRY_POINT
            };

            builder.SetTrigger(fetchTrigger);
            backgroundTask = builder.Register();
            Logger.Information("Created a new Background task with id: {ID}", backgroundTask.TaskId);
        }

        backgroundTask.Completed += BackgroundFetcher_Completed;
    }
```

My ApplicationTrigger is triggered by an DispatcherTimer once every 30 sec. The event triggered looks like this:

```
    private async void FetchTimerOnTick(object _sender, object _e)
    {
        var triggerResult = await fetchTrigger.RequestAsync();

        switch (triggerResult)
        {
            case ApplicationTriggerResult.Allowed:
                Logger.Information("Triggered fetching of data");
                break;
            case ApplicationTriggerResult.CurrentlyRunning:
                Logger.Information("Fetch task not complete yet. checking again in 30 sec");
                break;
            case ApplicationTriggerResult.DisabledByPolicy:
                Logger.Error("Fetch trigger disabled by policy");
                return;
            case ApplicationTriggerResult.UnknownError:
                Logger.Error("Fetch trigger had an unknown error");
                return;
        }
    }
```

My Run for my BackgroundTask looks like this:

```
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Logger.Information("Background fetcher started");
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        var timetableRequestTask = timeTablesModel.FetchTimeTables();
        var weatherRequestTask = weatherModel.FetchWeather();
        var newsRequestTask = newsTickerModel.FetchNews();

        Task.WaitAll(timetableRequestTask, weatherRequestTask, newsRequestTask);

        var fetchedData = new FetchedData
        {
            TimeTablesResponse = (TimeTablesResponse)timetableRequestTask.Result,
            WeatherUpdate = weatherRequestTask.Result,
            NewsResponse = (NewsResponse)newsRequestTask.Result
        };

        var path = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}BackgroundFetcherResultFile.json";

        using (var streamWriter = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, fetchedData);
                jsonWriter.Flush();
            }
        }

        Logger.Information("Background fetcher completed");

        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();

        deferral.Complete();

    }
```

The event for the backgroundTask.Completed looks like this:

```
    private async void BackgroundFetcher_Completed(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Logger.Information("Background task completed");

        try
        {
            args.CheckResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e, "Exception occured in background task");
            return;
        }

        FetchedData fetchedData;
        var path = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}BackgroundFetcherResultFile.json";

        using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                fetchedData = serializer.Deserialize<FetchedData>(jsonTextReader);
            }
        }

        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
         {
             if (fetchedData.TimeTablesResponse != null) timeTables.UpdateUi(fetchedData.TimeTablesResponse);

             var currentWeather = fetchedData.WeatherUpdate.CurrentWeather;
             var radar = fetchedData.WeatherUpdate.Radar;
             var forecast = fetchedData.WeatherUpdate.WeatherForecast;

             if (currentWeather != null) weather.UpdateCurrentWeatherUi(currentWeather);

             if (radar != null) weather.UpdateRadarUi(radar);

             if (forecast != null) weather.UpdateWeatherForecastUi(forecast);

             if (fetchedData.NewsResponse != null)
             {
                 news.UpdateNewsArticles(fetchedData.NewsResponse);
             }
         });
    }
```

The Completed event just parses the generated file and presents it in the GUI.

I can see in the logs that the string "Triggered fetching of data" appears repeatedly but when the string "Background task completed" stopps being printed in my logs.

Comment: What's the background [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#background-tasks-for-system-events) that you have used?

Comment: ApplicationTrigger. And I do call RequestAsync() which does return ApplicationTriggerResult.Allowed.

Comment: In general, mouse/keyboard disconnected will not effect `ApplicationTrigger` . And I also tested with official code sample, unfortunately, I could not reproduce this. The better way is that provide mini sample that could reproduce this issue for us.

Comment: I don't know anymore what is up or down! I tried to reproduce the bug with the BackgroundTask example code from GitHub and failed to do so. It works as intended.
I went over my code and compared it basically line for line with the example and did not find any fault.
I added a sleep in the background worker and all of a sudden it started to work. I have no clue why, but for now it seams to work and I'm not going to touch it! :P

Comment: Just when I finished to write that comment it stopped working!